# Java email - show multiple email recipients?

Tags: java, email

Is it possible to use Java to send an email such that I can see multiple recipients in the to/cc/bcc fields?

In other words, something like this:

```
From: foo@bar.com
To: user1@lol.com; user2@lol.com; user3@lol.com; user4@lol.com
Cc: admin1@lol.com; admin2@lol.com
```

I searched on Google but found no conclusive results, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is!
check out the [javax.mail library](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

Here is a code example:

```
class EmailSender{
private Properties properties;
private Session session;
private Message msg;
private final String SENDER_EMAIL  = "your.email@whatever.com";
private final String PWD = "***********";

public void sendMail(String body) throws Throwable{
    initMail();
    msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("SENDER_EMAIL"));
    //HERE YOU CAN CHOOSE BETWEEN TO, CC & BCC
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("Receiver Email"));
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("Receiver Email2"));
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("CC Email"));
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("CC Email2"));

    msg.setSubject("SUBJECT");
    msg.setText(body);

    //TRANSPORT
    Transport.send(msg);
    System.out.println("message sent!");
}

private void initMail(){
    //PROPERTIES
   //I choosed GMAIL for the demonstration, but you cant choose whatever you want.
    properties = new Properties(); 
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");


    //AUTHENTICATION
    session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(SENDER_EMAIL, PWD);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Don't forget to import the [javax.activation library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/activation/package-summary.html).

Comment: would you please accept the answer if it helped you so the question can be closed?
@ohseekay

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.
How to do it - depends on the library you're using.

Comment: Could you direct me to a library that can do this?

Comment: I've been working with Spring, and it definitely allows it. Check out http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.7/reference/mail.html

Comment: Do you know of a non-Spring library that can achieve this?

Comment: You can just use [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)